# Promp Javascript keep displaying

Tags: javascript

**I got an error,I do not know what is the problem with the code but even when I enter 3
into the prompt box, the browser keeps asking for the input without alert the message. One
more problem is when I enter 0 into the prompt box, it keeps asking for input without alert
Number 1-6. Can you guys show me what is the problem with the code?**

```
    var location1=3, location2=4, location3=5;
var guess;
var hit=0;
var guesses=0;
var isSunk=false;
while(isSunk==false){
    guess=prompt("User input: ");
    if(guess>0 || guess<=6){
        if(guess!==location1 || guess!==location2 || guess!==location3){
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
        }
        if (guess==location1 || guess==location2 || guess==location3){
            isSunk=true;
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
            
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Number 1 - 6");    
    }
}
alert('You win\nGuess is: '+guesses+' Hit is: '+hit);
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing your sunk condition correctly either. If you are trying to check if all 3 locations have been hit you will have to create an array to store hits to check if already hit and when the length of the array is 3 (assuming you only store correct hits) then change isSunk to true.

Comment: `guess>0 || guess<=6` read it out loud. If guess is greater than zero or guess is less than or equal to 6. So guess is 10. Is ten greater than zero, yes.... go into the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using short-circuit OR instead of short-circuit AND

Currently your code will allow any number to be input because you are allowing any number that is either > 0 or <= 6.

Also, you are saying that the guess is a miss if it is NOT 3 or NOT 4 or NOT 5. Every number matches this criteria.

Change your code to

```
while(isSunk==false){
    guess=prompt("User input: ");
    if(guess>0 && guess<=6){
        if(guess!==location1 && guess!==location2 && guess!==location3){
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
        }
        if (guess==location1 || guess==location2 || guess==location3){
            isSunk=true;
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
            
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Number 1 - 6");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using OR conditions for your if statement. An OR statement will run whenever any condition is true. This Means that since your input is always 1 value. Your first if statement will ALWAYS RUN as if you put in 3 then both location2 and location3 are correct as the input does not equal 4 or 5 respectively. In your check of guess you use OR as well so the same issue occurs.

Another note is that by using two if statements both can run. It is therefore better to use an if else like so

```
    var location1=3, location2=4, location3=5;
var guess;
var hit=0;
var guesses=0;
var isSunk=false;
while(isSunk==false){
    guess=prompt("User input: ");
    if(guess>0 && guess<=6){
        if (guess==location1 || guess==location2 || guess==location3){
            isSunk=true;
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
            
        }
        else {
            hit=hit+1;
            guesses=guesses+1;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Number 1 - 6");    
    }
}
alert('You win\nGuess is: '+guesses+' Hit is: '+hit);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers the question vote up to give some juicy rep to those that helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

1. if (guess > 0 || guess <= 6) => if (guess > 0 && guess < 6)
2. you could use else instead of another long if statement.
3. hit is always same as guesses in your code. why?

Here is the update

```
var location1=3, location2=4, location3=5;
var guess;
var hit=0;
var guesses=0;
var isSunk=false;
while(!isSunk){
    guess=Number(prompt("User input: "));
    if(guess>0 && guess<=6){
        if (guess===location1 || guess===location2 || guess===location3){
            isSunk=true;
        }
        hit=hit+1;
        guesses=guesses+1;
    }
    else{
        alert("Number 1 - 6");    
    }
}
alert('You win\nGuess is: '+guesses+' Hit is: '+hit);
```

Comment: That's actually a really smart way to do it. Since we know that both always increment. I salute you good sir, take your vote up.